# Existence of a Green's function equivalent to existence of bounded harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, riemann-surfaces, greens-function

I want to show the following are equivalent on a Riemann surface $W$:

1. Green's function $g_W (p, q)$ exists.
2. There exists a bounded harmonic function on $W$.
3. There exists a positive harmonic function on $W$.

Clearly 2. implies 3. I've shown 3. implies 1. via a Perron family argument, controlling the Perron family to which the Green's function is a solution. I suspect 1. implies 2. is similar, e.g. constructing a Perron family which is controlled by the Green's function, forcing the Perron solution to be bounded. However, I can't seem to get this to work, and I'm wondering if 1. implies 2. is necessarily true, since equivalence of 2. and 3. seems like a very strong statement.

It definitely holds for $W$ simply connected, as by the uniformization theorem $W$ is conformally equivalent with the disk, so we simply take the real/imaginary part of that conformal map. Along these lines, I was thinking of somehow using the fact that the covering space of $W$ is the disk and constructing a holomorphic right inverse $W \to \mathbb D$ to the covering map.

*Some definitions for clarity*: Let $W$ be a connected Riemann surface and $q \in W$. The map $g_W (p, q)$ is defined as the Perron solution to the family of compactly supported subharmonic functions $v: W \setminus \{q\} \to [-\infty, \infty)$ satisfying 
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{p \to q} [v(p) + \log |z(p)|] < \infty
\end{equation}
for some coordinate chart $z : U \to \mathbb D$ sending $p$ to the origin. We say the Green's function exists if

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a general remark about what happens with references but no proofs.

The result is not true in general; it is true if $W \subset \mathbb C$ by capacity theory, but otherwise both inclusions are strict -

(Riemann surfaces satisfying 1 are also called hyperbolic, while those that do not satisfy 2 are called $O_{HB}$, and those that do not satisfy 3 are called $O_{HP}$ and there a few more classes coming from the existence or not of bounded analytic functions, harmonic functions with bounded Dirichlet integral etc - in the plane the complement of the usual Cantor set is hyperbolic - positive capacity - hence admits bounded harmonic functions, but the Cantor set has Lebesgue measure zero, so its complement doesn't admit bounded analytic functions).

Counterexamples are complicated and for example, the book by [Ahlfors and Sario on Riemann Surfaces](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691652443/riemann-surfaces) has them in chapter 4, while the proof that $1$ implies $2$ for planar surfaces is classic and appears in Ahlfors and Sario but also in [Conway Functions of One Complex Variable II](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387944609)